# How to express three alternatives?

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “either” only used with two options?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40950/is-either-only-used-with-two-options)

I'm trying to find a way to express that there are three alternatives in a sentence. For example, if there were two alternatives, I could say:

> That person could be either Alice or Lily.

But what if I want to add a third person? Can I say:

> That person could be either Alice, Lily or Lucy.

I looked up in the dictionary and it says:

> either/or: an unavoidable choice between two alternatives.

Well, how do I express an unavoidable choice between three or more alternatives?

Comment: @Xavier: I think it would be a bad idea to use that construct in this case. (Grant you, there are times when that construct _could_ be used to "express a choice between three or more alternatives," but, in this example, it sounds off.  Moreover, structuring a sentence that way out of a love for "verbose sentences" probably won't lead to strong writing.) P.S. I notice you're still ending comments with unnecessary exclamation points.

Comment: Also see [Equivalent of “both” when referring three or more items?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22357),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to say *That person could be Alice, Lily or Lucy*. *That person*, in the singular, indicates that only one choice is possible.

Comment: The OED does include a sense of *either* that means any one of more than two, but it is not a particularly common usage.

Comment: @tchrist: So I see, but the etymology seems to be on the side of two. Of course, 'either' isn't necessary even when the choice is between two: 'That person could be Alice or Lucy'.

Comment: I don't see why OP uses *"**could** be"* if it's important to convey that it's definitely one of the three alternatives, and not some completely different unnamed person. I'd just say *"That person **must** be Alice, Lily or Lucy"*