# Should there be a comma after an M-dashed, parenthetic phrase

Tags: punctuation, parentheticals

Should there be a comma — is this comma necessary? —, after an M-dashed, parenthetic phrase? And are those spaces necessary, on both sides of the parenthetic phrase? (ignore the '?', but as a third question, could punctuation in a parenthetic phrase impact the outer sentence?)

Comment: As far as spaces around em dashes, this has [already been asked](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154996/spaces-and-em-dash) - it's a matter of choice with most style guides saying no spaces.

Comment: As for commas after dashes, this has been asked before. There is some support for putting them there but opinions are divided: Fowler says keep, Chicago says drop; personally I think it looks ugly with the comma. Does this answer your question? [How is punctuation used after dashes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9816/how-is-punctuation-used-after-dashes)

Comment: I'd add that dash + question mark is also ugly and bracketed queries-within-parentheticals are far to be preferred. // Good sleuthing, @Stuart.